# Breeze EntityQuery.from() withParameters POST to API not working

Tags: post, breeze, http-status-code-405

I have this peace of code :

```
function getSopMatches(data) {

        return EntityQuery.from('GetSopMatches')
            .withParameters({
                $method: 'POST',
                $encoding: 'JSON',
                $data: data
            })
            .using(manager).execute()
            .then(success)
            .catch(_queryFailed);

        function success(response) {
            return response.results;
        }
    }
```

and it is called through this :

```
playerService.getSopMatches({ playerId: vm.player.id, competitionId: career.competitionId, seasonId: career.seasonId, teamId: career.teamId }).then(function (results) { //do something with it });
```

In my MVC controller (BreezeController) the method is like :

```
[HttpPost]
    public IQueryable<object> GetSopMatches(SopMatch sop)
    {
        //this method is not called, I get a 405 Method not Allowed
    }
```

Somehow, the actual call is a GET, instead of a POST and therefore I get the 405 Method not Allowed error message.

I have other peaces of code in the same project (client side javascript/breeze calls and server side mvc controller methods) that do work.

Does anybody knows what I'm doing wrong, or why it is changed to a GET method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a day of trying and failing, I found a solution.

It appeared that in the angular controller I was injecting breeze, and that was causing the issue. When breeze is injected into the controller or service, it messes up the URL of the POST and therefore you receive a 405 (because the URL is changed).

Comment: How did you fixe it ?

Comment: I found the answer by myself, the solution is in the documentation : breeze.ajaxPost() need to be call (http://breeze.github.io/doc-breeze-labs/ajax-post.html)